# How do 2 or more threads get synchronized using a timer in the Windows kernel?

Tags: windows, synchronization, multithreading, kernel, timer

I have been reading about the kernel using timers for thread synchronization.  I haven't been able to find a decent explanation on how thread sync with timers works, I wondered if anyone can help me?

MSDN: [Kernel Dispatcher objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa490206.aspx)

[DPCs and timer objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa490171.aspx) <-- here it talks about 'synchronization timers'

Also reading book Windows Internals 5 by Microsoft Press where it mentions them.

EDIT: *My question is: How do 2 or more threads get synchronized using a timer in the kernel?*

Comment: Windows, C++ or C# for any examples

Comment: Could you source these readings?  I'm not 100% on what you're talking about.

Comment: edited my post to include data requested.

Comment: I still don't understand what you want to know. Do you want to know how it works in the actual Windows kernel, or how these concepts could be applied elsewhere? It's really helpful if the last or first sentence of your question poses a question other than 'can anyone help me?' the answer to that is a resounding 'maybe.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wait on a timer just like events or other objects. Let us say you want two threads to do something when a timer expires, you set up a notification timer and make both threads wait on the same timer by using KeWaitForSingleObject